# cookie support in blackberry os 4 and above

Tags: php, blackberry, cookies, operating-system

I've developed a web application for mobile. As I'm new to mobile web development I'm little worried about the support for cookies in smart phones. Application is targeted to be viewed in iPhone,  Android supported mobiles, blackberry OS 4 or above versions. I'm not aware of all features which are support on our desktop PC browser and mobile browser.

My application is ready I've tested on my desktop but not on any smart phone. I don't know JAVA and used PHP to develop the application. Monday I've to give demo of the application to client.

Can any one will tell me whether worries are acceptable.. Can I give demo without checking/confirming the app on blackberry device(as client want to see the application on blackberry OS 4 and above). How should I test app on different devices. with buying any device...

Please help me...

Comment: My experience with mobile platforms shows that you cannot be sure that your app will work on any device until you actually try it on a physical device.  Simulators are great for getting you close, but not a substitute for a real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are supported by the BlackBerry web browser, even going back to version 4.x of the OS.

To test your application, you can download a BlackBerry simulator from:

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp

For older simulators (4.x for certain), you will need to first start the MDS simulator, which allows the phone simulator to connect to the internet through its web browser.

You can download the MDS simulator package from here:

https://swdownloads.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=996009F2374006606F4C0B0FDA878AF1

With web application testing, the BlackBerry web browser doesn't contain many discrepancies between the simulator and the physical device -- the simulator's browser is a good indicator of how your application will feel on the real BlackBerry web browser. It has all the same configurable options, so you can test how your application behaves if the user chooses to turn off the cookies in their BlackBerry browser.

A more comprehensive tutorial, with screenshots, is [available here](http://www.andreybutov.com/2011/08/05/testing-your-web-app-on-a-blackberry-simulator/).